# XT90 with AWG 10 wire?

Tags: wire, maximum-ratings, plug

XT90 plugs support up to 90A continous current and up tp 120A for short bursts.

On the other hand the only allow AWG 10 (5mm²) wires. AWG 10 is rated for ~50A
https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wire-gauges-d_419.html

https://www.elektromodellflug.de/hochstrom-st.-bu..html

How is this save? Is there some safety margin used? How hot will the wire get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those AWG ratings are for in wall wiring with more fire hazards due to heating. On a model airplane you can get away with smaller AWG. Same thing with Anderson PowerPole connectors. They are rated for 45A due to their intended application but people run them hotter on model aircraft.

You don't want something too hot to touch buried in your wall, but on a model plane it is not as big a deal. Plus you have lots of air flow.

Wire ampacity is not a hard number and can vary a lot based on operating conditions. It's not really to stop the metal core from melting. The insulation will melt long before that and the heat might make something else nearby melt or catch fire before that. That's how ampacity is chosen.

There are NFPA (fire code) that have ampacities less than half of what your tables have.